# realizar un select join de tres tablas desde una view en django

Tags: python, mysql, django

Necesito para una aplicación de una tienda de ropa sacar todos los productos y las tallas de ropa para las que se encuentran disponibles cada prenda en cuestión. para ello tengo tres tablas, de la primera tabla quiero usar el id del producto

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Nombre')
    description = RichTextField(verbose_name='Descripcion')
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Precio")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, verbose_name='Usuario', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    talla = models.ManyToManyField(Size_clothes, verbose_name='Tallas', blank=True)
```

De la segunda tabla quiero sacar el campo de name_size:

```
class Size_clothes(models.Model):
    name_size = models.CharField(max_length=6, verbose_name='Talla del producto')
    description_size = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Descripcion de la talla')
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Creado el')
```

Y la tercera tabla es la que se encarga de relacionar una tabla con la otra, esa tabla no la cree a través de los modelos sino que se creo sola al haber una relación de manytomany. la estructura de la tabla es la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde mysql he conseguido el resultado que deseaba a través de la siguiente consulta:

```
select t1.product_id, t2.name_size from tienda_product_talla t1 join tienda_size_clothes t2 on t1.size_clothes_id = t2.id;
```

Como se puede ver con mysql pude hacerla tan solo utilizando esas dos tablas, la relacional y la de las tallas, el problema es que no se como hacerlo en la view de django

Answer (score 2):

vale, ya he encontrado como se hace resulta que puedes invocar a datos que residan en otras tablas utilizando la clausula `select_related` esta busca a través de una clave foránea en las tablas que estén relacionadas con ella.

Dejo aquí el hilo de StackOverflow en ingles donde lo explica un usuario:
[django views py how to perform the inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778114/django-views-py-how-to-perform-the-inner-join)

Para mi caso solo realice la siguiente sentencia:

```
lista_tallas = Product.objects.all().select_related('talla').values_list('id', 'talla__name_size')
```

Con las dobles barra bajas en la clausula `values_list` sacas el dato de la tabla foránea, como yo he hecho con `talla__name_size`